# Visual Studio 2010 Extension - Show infobar on top of document

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, vs-extensibility

Starting from Visual Studio 2015, the extensions SDK supports showing an infobar on top of a document window: see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt300796.aspx#BKMK_Infobars.
Unfortunately that functionallity is not available for VS2010.
As our extension also needs to support older Visual Studio versions, starting from Visual Studio 2010, is there another possible solution to show an infobar on top of a document window?

I tried to use margins, to dynamically show an info bar. But that doesn't work well. It looks like Visual Studio doesn't like the fact that I'm changing the size of the margin when I show/hide an item in the infobar margin.

Comment: You might have to settle for a MsgBox or TaskBar notification or something for VS versions < 2015. As per [MSDN Converting Add-ins to VSPackage Extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn246938.aspx): *Starting in Visual Studio 2015, for C# and Visual Basic projects, you can use the VSIX project and add item templates for menu commands, tool windows, and VSPackages.* Its a different technology in 2015 that support InfoBars. Whats the Extension out of curiosity?

Comment: There is an InformationBar in the [Productivity Power Tools extension](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lisa/2010/07/24/visual-studio-2010-productivity-power-tools-updated-with-tools-option-support-and-more/) for the mixed tab/spaces warning. Recently the VS2015 version of that extension was open sourced, and it still has a [InformationBar](https://github.com/Microsoft/VS-PPT/blob/master/src/FixMixedTabs/Impl/InformationBar.cs) class. I'm not sure if the VS2015 one is still the same as in VS2010, but it might be a good start.